# Rails Undefined Column Error after updating gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was upgrading my portfolio site where I uploaded a new video file, when I checked it on my local server the page was looking good, then I decided to update sprockets and bootstrap because of security issues.

I ran a `bundle update` as well as `bundle install`, I upgraded to sprockets 3.2.7 and Bootstrap 4.1.2 whereas before it was 4.0alpha.

I have eliminated Bootstrap gem as a possibility.

It was after this that my blog page and only my blog page broke with the following error message:

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column blogs.topic_id does not exist

from the `_blog_sidebar.html.erb`:

```
<div class="sidebar-module">
    <h4>Topics</h4>
    <% @side_bar_topics.each do |topic| %>
      <p><%= link_to topic.title, topic_path(topic) %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

It points to the each loop saying that I am missing the field of `topic_id` on the `Blog` model?

How does that happen by updating gems? Has anyone have this happen before? If so how did you fix it?

Here is my `schema.rb` file where you can see `topic_id`:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170930175841) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "status", default: 0
    t.bigint "topic_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["topic_id"], name: "index_blogs_on_topic_id"
  end
```

I have followed the `has_many` and `belongs_to` conventions:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

`blog.rb`:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {draft: 0, published: 1}
  extend FriendlyId

  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  validates_presence_of :title, :body, :topic_id

  belongs_to :topic

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  def self.special_blogs
    all
  end

  def self.featured_blogs
    limit(2)
  end

  def self.recent
    order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

`topic.rb`:

```
class Topic < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :title

    has_many :blogs

    def self.with_blogs
        includes(:blogs).where.not(blogs: {id: nil})
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by running a `rake db:drop`, `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate`.